# How to get location in background on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, cllocationmanager, background-process

i am developing app that get location in backGround even app is killed also.

My code is working fine in Simulator. but not Working in Any ios device. i have tested in iphone5s version(7.1) iphone4s(7.1) ipad 7.1 also.

Here is my code link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1x0uuhk0xb35bct/DUhQ20wC2j

Please Download and Suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you app is killed there is no way to keep location tracking going. It's up to the user if your app is running or not. Also just posting your code without specifying what is working and what is not is not a good way to questions. Read the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @rckoenes If your app is registered for significantLocationChange, your app will receive location updates even if it is not running.

Comment: @Apurv that makes no sense, if you app is not running, there is noway you can handle any location changes, since your app is not running. You mean that if the have a background mode `locationtackin` then yes when your app is background you will receive location update. But if you app is killed there is noway to keep code running.

Comment: @rckoenes, please see this statement from Apple doc. "If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives."

Comment: @Apurv I stand corrected, [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) does mention this. Although in my experience my ap never got started again after it was killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case when your application is moved to background, you should register for significant location changes.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

When application becomes active, you should do reverse to track the user aggressively.